# Is there any way to add `application` tag to standard prometheus micrometer metrics?

Tags: spring-boot, prometheus, spring-boot-actuator, micrometer

I have few spring-boot microservices with actuator and exposed prometheus metrics. For example:

```
# HELP process_uptime_seconds The uptime of the Java virtual machine
# TYPE process_uptime_seconds gauge
process_uptime_seconds 3074.971
```

But there is no `application` tag, so I'm not able to bind it to a certain application within a grafana dashboard...

Also I expect to have few application instances of some microservice, so in general it would be great to add an `instance` tag also.

Is there any way to customize the standard metrics with these tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to add tags is to use the Prometheus service discovery. This keeps these tags out of your application code and keeps it from being concerned about where it exists.

However sometime if you absolutely need those extra tags (due to the service having extra insight that Prometheus service discovery isn't surfacing) you can't use the Java Simple Client (the Go client does support this though)

I turns out this feature is offered via a Micrometer feature called 'Common Tags' which wraps the Prometheus Java client. You setup your client so the tags are available via a config() call.

```
registry.config().commonTags("stack", "prod", "region", "us-east-1");
```

Comment: Thank you, I got the idea. To configure it within spring I've created a bean that implements `MeterRegistryCustomizer<MeterRegistry>` interface and configured the registry with common tags application-wide!!

Answer (score 5):

What I am usually doing is using Maven filtering on the resource files (e.g. application.yml) which will replace Maven-known properties like `project.artifactId`. Springs configuration then takes care of interpolating `management.metrics.tags.application`.

An application.yml example:

```yaml
spring:
  application:
    name: ${project.artifactId}
management:    
  metrics:
    tags:
      application: ${spring.application.name}
```